# UPDATE tbl SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE(`name`,[:digit:],'')

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to get rid of some digits in my table.
What is wrong with this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET `name` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`name`,[:digit:],'')
```

it won't execute showing: REGEXP_REPLACE is not valid at this position...

thanx.

Comment: Enclose `[:digit:]` inside single quotes: `'[:digit:]'`.

Comment: good, that got me:
Error Code: 1139. Got error 'POSIX named classes are supported only within a class at offset ' from regexp.
Which I solved by using another set of [ ] 
`'[[:digit:]]'`

Answer (score 0):

You put the field between comma: `'name'`. Your query is trying to REGEXP replace inside the text 'name'. Rremove the quotes to replace your field value:

```
UPDATE tbl SET name = REGEXP_REPLACE(name,[:digit:],'')
```

Comment: I used backticks not quotes, either way, same error...